# Rails rspec after_save reference self

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I want to add a profanity check on my website.

I'm taking a TD approach and I'm trying the following:

1. check if profanity exists in specific profile fields
2. create a flag
3. create a flag if one does not exist
4. create a flag if one exists, but has been dismissed

Here is my spec so far:

```
describe Painter do
  before do
    @painter = FactoryGirl.create(:painter_flag)
  end

  context "blacklist flag" do
    it "check if profanity exists" do
      @painter.experience = "test"
      @painter.save
      expect {@painter.blacklist_flags?}.to be_true
    end
    it "create flag if profanity exists" do
      @painter.experience = "test"
      @painter.save
      BlacklistFlag.count.should be > 0
    end
  end
end
```

Painter related code:

```
after_save :create_flag, if: :blacklist_flags?

def blacklist_flags?
    list = ""
    list << skills
    #list << experience
    #list << first_name
    #list << last_name
    #list.downcase.scan(/(badword|badword)/).size > 0
  end

def create_flag
end
```

If I comment out the following code above the two test pass:

```
 list << skills
```

When I leave the code in I receive the following error:

**2) Painter blacklist flag create flag if profanity exists
     Failure/Error: @painter = FactoryGirl.create(:painter_flag)
     TypeError:
       can't convert nil into String**

It seems there's a problem with referencing self because skills, experience, etc are part of the model. I'm not sure how to fix this. Please advise.

Update:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :painter do
    first_name "Brian"
    last_name  "Rosedale"
    state "OH"
    zip_code "43081"
    sequence(:email) {|n| "nobody#{n}@painterprofessions.com" }
    phone "12345566"
    pdca_member false
    password "123456"
    factory :painter_flag do
       skills = "badword"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Your factory for `:painter_flag` seems to be creating objects without setting the `skills` attribute/association. Can you post that code?

Comment: Hi depa, please see the update above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this line in your factory for `:painter_flag`, without the `=` sign.

```
skills "badword"
```

Comment: Nice, did it work? Please don't forget to pick the answer as the correct one if it did.

Answer (score 0):

I think what's causing the error is because the callback is been executed on the line `@painter = FactoryGirl.create(:painter_flag)`.

You might want to use `FactoryGirl.build` method if you want to test the callback.